# Removing empty polygon from sf object in R?

Tags: r, polygon, sf

I have such object:

```
> p_mb
Simple feature collection with 52 features and 0 fields (with 9 geometries empty)
geometry type:  GEOMETRY
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 585001.4 ymin: 211001.9 xmax: 609998.1 ymax: 236998.6
epsg (SRID):    NA
proj4string:    NA
First 10 features:
                         geometry
1  POLYGON ((591051.4 211855, ...
2                   POLYGON EMPTY
3  POLYGON ((588206.4 212570, ...
4  MULTIPOLYGON (((585004.6 21...
5  POLYGON ((600614.5 216112.9...
6  POLYGON ((603033.8 215125.2...
7  MULTIPOLYGON (((608168.4 21...
8  POLYGON ((600009.4 212984, ...
9  POLYGON ((603203.4 217336, ...
10 POLYGON ((585519.4 217546, ...
```

obtained from negative buffering other sf object. My question is simple, how to delete those empty slots to not get error and warnings:

```
> p_pol <- sf::st_cast(p_mb0, "POLYGON")
There were 23 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
> warnings()
1: In st_cast.MULTIPOLYGON(X[[i]], ...) : polygon from first part only
2: In st_cast.MULTIPOLYGON(X[[i]], ...) : polygon from first part only
3: In st_cast.MULTIPOLYGON(X[[i]], ...) : polygon from first part only
4: In st_cast.MULTIPOLYGON(X[[i]], ...) : polygon from first part only
5: In st_cast.MULTIPOLYGON(X[[i]], ...) : polygon from first part only
6: In st_cast.MULTIPOLYGON(X[[i]], ...) : polygon from first part only
7: In st_cast.MULTIPOLYGON(X[[i]], ...) : polygon from first part only
8: In st_cast.MULTIPOLYGON(X[[i]], ...) : polygon from first part only
9: In st_cast.MULTIPOLYGON(X[[i]], ...) : polygon from first part only
10: In st_cast.MULTIPOLYGON(X[[i]], ...) : polygon from first part only
11: In st_cast.MULTIPOLYGON(X[[i]], ...) : polygon from first part only
12: In st_cast.MULTIPOLYGON(X[[i]], ...) : polygon from first part only
13: In st_cast.MULTIPOLYGON(X[[i]], ...) : polygon from first part only
14: In st_cast.MULTIPOLYGON(X[[i]], ...) : polygon from first part only
15: In st_cast.MULTIPOLYGON(X[[i]], ...) : polygon from first part only
16: In st_cast.MULTIPOLYGON(X[[i]], ...) : polygon from first part only
17: In st_cast.MULTIPOLYGON(X[[i]], ...) : polygon from first part only
18: In st_cast.MULTIPOLYGON(X[[i]], ...) : polygon from first part only
19: In st_cast.MULTIPOLYGON(X[[i]], ...) : polygon from first part only
20: In st_cast.MULTIPOLYGON(X[[i]], ...) : polygon from first part only
21: In st_cast.MULTIPOLYGON(X[[i]], ...) : polygon from first part only
22: In st_cast.MULTIPOLYGON(X[[i]], ...) : polygon from first part only
23: In st_cast.MULTIPOLYGON(X[[i]], ...) : polygon from first part only

> spl_mbuf <- as(p_pol, "Spatial")
Error: length(srl) > 0 is not TRUE
```

I think I can skip those warnings.

---

Found workaround: just used `p_uni <- sf::st_union(p_mb)` after buffer, but this is only emergency exit.

Answer (score 19):

My first guess was to use `st_area` and select for those with area greater than zero. But I looked at the docs and found `st_is_empty`. For example here's some constructed test data:

```
> p = st_point(c(1,1))
> pv = st_sfc(p,p,p,p,p)
> bv = st_buffer(pv, c(1,1,0,-1,2))
> d = st_sf(bv)
> d$ID=1:5
```

Which has two empty polygons:

```
> d
Simple feature collection with 5 features and 1 field (with 2 geometries empty)
geometry type:  POLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: -1 ymin: -1 xmax: 3 ymax: 3
epsg (SRID):    NA
proj4string:    NA
                              bv ID
1 POLYGON ((2 1, 1.99863 0.94...  1
2 POLYGON ((2 1, 1.99863 0.94...  2
3                  POLYGON EMPTY  3
4                  POLYGON EMPTY  4
5 POLYGON ((3 1, 2.997259 0.8...  5
```

Get only the non-empty with:

```
> dne = d[!st_is_empty(d),,drop=FALSE]
> dne
Simple feature collection with 3 features and 1 field
geometry type:  POLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: -1 ymin: -1 xmax: 3 ymax: 3
epsg (SRID):    NA
proj4string:    NA
                              bv ID
1 POLYGON ((2 1, 1.99863 0.94...  1
2 POLYGON ((2 1, 1.99863 0.94...  2
5 POLYGON ((3 1, 2.997259 0.8...  5
>
```

Answer (score 19):

Building off of the answer by @Spacedman, you can filter out empty geometries using `st_is_empty` with a tidyverse approach

```
dne <- d %>% filter(!st_is_empty(.))
```

Answer (score 4):

In the event that `st_is_empty()` gives you an error of:

> Error in CPL_geos_is_empty(st_geometry(x)) :
> Evaluation error: IllegalArgumentException: point array must contain 0 or >1 elements.

You can use:

```
dne <- d %>% filter( is.na(st_dimension(.)) == FALSE )
```

Information on checking for empty geometries can be found here: https://r-spatial.org/r/2017/03/19/invalid.html#empty-geometries